# MATLAB 7.12 R2011a Neural Network Toolbox - Does the value of net.numLayers include the input layer?

Tags: networking, layer, matlab, neural-network

I am creating a neural network using MATLAB (version specified in title).

After reading the documentation and research on the internet, I am still confused as to whether net.numLayers includes the input layer.

In other words, if I want to create a 3-Layer neural network as follows:

*Input Layer - Hidden Layer - Output Layer*

should I specify

**net.numLayers = 3** or **net.numLayers = 2**?

I am confused because there is a command **net.inputs{i}.range** where **i** specifies the *index* on the input layer. May I remind you that **i** is "0" if it does not exist, otherwise it should be a positive integer. (Please refer to the documentation for more details)

However many tutorials on the internet which seem reliable are making me think otherwise:

http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~csolb/CscI1900/xor.htm
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~someshs/nn/matlab_nn_starter.htm

If you have a look at the links provided, you will realize that they build a neural network for the XOR function. I am aware that the version of MATLAB may be different, however most of the commands are the same, otherwise in the newer version there is different syntax for the equivalent functionality. In both tutorials the number of layers specified is 2 (for hidden and output layer), but the second tutorial makes use `net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'logsig';` where **"1"** would definitely be referring to the hidden layer.

If someone could clarify this it would be very helpful.

I look forward to reading some answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not include the input layer.

Here is a trick, after you have created your network (say, net=feedforwardnet(10), where the 10 is the size of your input layers). You could type view(net) to get a visual view of the network[image]